# Retrieving data from database and write it into html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql database using php and write that data to html web page. But all I see is blank, it writes nothing and I can't find where the mistake is. I changed localhost phpMyadmin's password, so that can't be wrong. I don't get any "cannot connected to database" error either.

Here is my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Kaç Yakıyor?</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    background-color:#CCC;
}
h1.header
{
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size:45px;
    font-style:oblique;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
}
div.content
{
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:61%;
    background-color:#F00;
}
div.vehicles
{
    margin-top:100px;
    width:17%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#0F6;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","123123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kacyakiyor") or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT marka from arabalar";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
        <h1 class="header">KAÇ YAKIYOR</h1>
        <hr width="500px"/>
        <div class="vehicles">
        <h2><strong><em>Araba</em></strong></h2><hr/><br/>
        <?php echo "$row['marka']"; ?>
        <h2><strong><em>Motosiklet</em></strong></h2><hr/><br/></div>
        <div class="content">asdfasfda
        </div>
<?php
    }
}
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing `<?php echo "$row['marka']"; ?>` to `<?php echo $row['marka']; ?>` see if that helps/makes a difference.

Comment: run this query SELECT marka from arabalar in phpMyadmin and see what you get..

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);print_r($row);exit; try this before writing  in html

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? No output (i.e. `<h1>` and stuffs) at all? Output but the php part is empty?

Comment: And maybe `$query = "SELECT * marka from arabalar";`

Comment: use print_r($row); inside while loop and check whether it prints something

Comment: @Passerby Of course the php part is empty, html parts are ok.

Comment: it may be there is no output from the query use mysql_num_rows($result); and check whether it has output count greater than 0

Comment: @Sonali i get what i want when i run my query in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Miral - a. Did you make the change mentioned by Fred -ii-? b. What was the result of Sudhakar's suggestion?

Comment: @sudhakar I tried but still no changes at all

Comment: Also, after the `if ($result) { ... }` add `else { die(mysql_error()); }` and see if that gives an error message

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox Yes i made and i still get no data.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox I'm kind of new to php so where should I get this error? I'm asking because I did what you said and got no error.

Comment: Remove style definitions for div.vehicles from the container (or change class='vehicles' to  class='vehiclesx').  css might be hiding your contents from you

Comment: It should just spit the error out on the screen. Also add `var_dump($result);` right after the mysql_query() to confirm it's returning a result resource.

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan no it doesn't.

Comment: @Miral if it doesn't how do you expect it to be print inside the html. there is no result hence nothing is printed

Answer (score 4):

put this code

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","123123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kacyakiyor",$conn);
```

instead of

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","123123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kacyakiyor") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Stylistically that may be a good idea, but it shouldn't make a difference in this case. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Comment: Nothing is changed, still no data.

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error in `<?php echo "$row['marka']"; ?>` , here no need to wrap in `quatation`.

**Replace**

```
<?php echo "$row['marka']"; ?>
```

**With**

```
<?php echo $row['marka']; ?>
```

**Edit**

Add `$result` = `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and try to see its through any error message ?

Comment: @Miral Actually, that was "my" suggestion from original / first comment.

Comment: @DevangRathod By "Nope" at my first comment to this question, I ment "no, it's not working."

Comment: @Miral have you tried `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` ?

Comment: @DevangRathod No I haven't but I think the query isn't wrong because I see a result when I run this query at phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @Miral `echo "hello";` inside `if($result){` and then check its echoing or not inside if condition ?

Comment: @DevangRathod I was thinking the same thing. I checked and you're right, its not echoing anything. But, I deleted `if($result){` part and nothing has changed. It still not echoing anything.

Comment: @Miral inside while loop your html data is displayed or not ?

Comment: @Miral try `mysql_fetch_assoc` and check.

Comment: @Miral try this without password `mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @DevangRathod I just went to eat something and no it's not.

Comment: @Miral ohhh its really strange issues.

Comment: @Miral check again your database name and table name maybe some issues is there ?

Comment: @DevangRathod yeah, thanks for help anyway. Nope, those are true I checked.

Comment: @Miral you have css set for `div.vehicles` remove that css code i am sure that will solve the issues... because you are using `float` and margin-top...and playing with floated div is really hard for the newbie

Comment: @DevangRathod I deleted but see no difference.

Comment: @Miral you accept or not but there must be a some spelling mistake in database name or table name or field name.

Comment: @DevangRathod omg I was so stupid that I can't express it by words. I've just found the mistake. I saved my file with .html extension not .php! Wow I've never been more stupid. Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: @Miral , anyway no problem important is your solution.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
mysql_fetch_row() //and

echo $row['marka']
```

instead of,

```
mysql_fetch_array //and
echo "$row['marka']"
```

Comment: Actually `echo "$row['marka']"` should throw a parse error. It may depend on PHP version, but it won't expand an element from an associative array inside a string - you'd have to use curly brackets for that -- this would work: `"{$row['marka']}"`